# Get result from xml code with python

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7, xml-parsing

I have an xml code from nimbuzz chat app which searches for a chatroom in nimbuzz server using input keyword.

```
<iq type="set" id="Nimbuzz_SearchRooms" to="conference.nimbuzz.com"><query xmlns="jabber:iqearch"><set xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/rsm"><index>0</index><max>10</max></set><x type="get" xmlns="jabberata"><field var="name"><value>**INPUT KEYWORD FOR ROOM NAME**</value></field><field var="include_password_protected"><value>true</value></field></x></query></iq>
```

The code is working and I'm getting the following result as xml code:

**See the image:**

[The result code image](http://qfs.mobi/f1833352)

I started with this code but I can't complete it because I can't understand how it works:

```
def handler_search_room(type, source, parameters):
    Key_word = raw_input("Please write the Key word: ")
    if parameters.split():
        iq = xmpp.Iq('set')
        iq.setID('Nimbuzz_SearchRooms')
        iq.setTo('conference.nimbuzz.com)
```

I need to send the first code to the nimbuzz server and then I need to get the result with the information of each Chatroom.
The result code should get this information for each chatroom:

- name
- subject.
- num_users
- num_max_users
- is_passowrd_protected
- is_member_only
- language
- location-type
- location

How can I do that with python? I will happy if someone would help me to make my code.

**Download the XML code if you want:**

http://qfs.mobi/f1833350

Answer (score 0):

```
def handler_akif_room(type, source, parameters):
        room = parameters
        if parameters.split():
        iq = xmpp.Iq('set')
        iq.setID('Nimbuzz_SearchRooms')
                iq.setTo('conference.nimbuzz.com')
                query = xmpp.Node('query') 
                query.setNamespace('jabber:iq:search')
                iq.addChild(node=query) 

                sett = xmpp.Node('set')
                sett.setNamespace('http://jabber.org/protocol/rsm')
                query.addChild(node=sett)

                sifir = "0"
                ind = xmpp.Node('index')
                ind.setData(sifir)
                sett.addChild(node=ind)

                on = "10"
                maxx = xmpp.Node('max')
                maxx.setData(on)
                sett.addChild(node=maxx)

                qqx = xmpp.Node('x')
                qqx.setNamespace('jabber:x:data" type="get')
                query.addChild(node=qqx)

                field = xmpp.Node('field')
                field.setAttr('var','name')
                field.setData(' ') 
                qqx.addChild(node=field)

                valueone = xmpp.Node('value')
                valueone.setData(room)
                field.addChild(node=valueone)



                fieldtwo = xmpp.Node('field')
                fieldtwo.setAttr('var','include_password_protected')
                fieldtwo.setData(' ')
                qqx.addChild(node=fieldtwo)

                valuetwo = xmpp.Node('value')
                valuetwo.setData('true')
                fieldtwo.addChild(node=valuetwo)


        JCON.SendAndCallForResponse(iq, handler_akif_room_answ, {'type': type, 'source': source})
        msg(source[1], u''+str(iq)+' .') ## <= OUT SHOW :)) GOOD WORK! CONTACT ME akif@nimbuzz.com :)
```